# How to save jtable to excel including headers using poi?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, apache-poi

How can I get the JTable header to save in excel i have a code that only the values are saved but header is not including im using POI 3.14 heres my code

```
for (int i = 0; i <  model.getRowCount(); i++) {
  XSSFRow excelRow = excelSheet.createRow(i);
   for (int j = 0; j <  model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
     XSSFCell excelCell = excelRow.createCell(j);
     excelCell.setCellValue(model.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
     }
 }
```

Comment: Look at [`JTable#getColumnModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getColumnModel())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my solution thanks

```
` for (int i = 0; i <  model.getRowCount()+1; i++) {
      SSFRow excelRow = excelSheet.createRow(i);
      for (int j = 0; j <  model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
          if(i == 0){
                XSSFCell excelCell = excelRow.createCell(j);
                excelCell.setCellValue(model.getColumnName(j));
           }else{
                 XSSFCell excelCell = excelRow.createCell(j);
                 excelCell.setCellValue(model.getValueAt(i-1, j).toString());
                 }
        }
  }`
```

Comment: by using model.getColumnName() to get the header value